# VCALENDAR Timezone and DST in Outlook 2007

Tags: icalendar

I have a problem with ical while opening in outlook 2007, it shows 1 hour ahead in australian time zone and one hour behind in other locations.
It wil be a great help, if some body could figure it out, 
Following is the .ico file content.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16010101T000000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=4
TZOFFSETFROM:+1100
TZOFFSETTO:+1000
TZNAME:Standard Time
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:16010101T000000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=10
TZOFFSETFROM:+1000
TZOFFSETTO:+1100
TZNAME:Daylight Saving Time
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;CN="ullas ";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:ullasjn@gmail.com
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:ullasjn@gmail.com
DTSTART;TZID="Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney":20091019T180000
DTEND;TZID="Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney":20091019T183000
LOCATION:Melb-L19 Room 8
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SEQUENCE:1
UID:rtwj2xbjvihflu5540kyy055_3379_633915722919214986
DTSTAMP:20091019T184901Z
SUMMARY:CMS[Ref#:10300][UPDATED: Meeting reservation]
DESCRIPTION: Melb-L19 Room 8\n\nMeeting Starting Time:   2009/10/19 18:00\nMeeting Ending Time:     2009/10/19 18:30\n\n AUST TIME : 18-18.30\n\n\n
PRIORITY:5
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
CLASS:PUBLIC
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: have you checked to Day Light Savings ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you can control, or where the ical data is coming from, but what if you change the TZID to 'Australia/Melbourne' or 'Australia/Sydney'?

```
DTSTART;TZID="Australia/Sydney":20091019T180000 
DTEND;TZID="Australia/Sydney":20091019T183000
```

This may not be the latest, but this is the VTIMEZONE record I have.

```
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Australia/Sydney
X-LIC-LOCATION:Australia/Sydney
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:+1000
TZOFFSETTO:+1100
TZNAME:EST
DTSTART:19701025T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+1000
TZOFFSETTO:+1000
TZNAME:EST
DTSTART:19700329T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this type of problem when you see one or two hours more or less from what you expect is related with daylight saving times.

I recommend you to check which is the correct current time here:

http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=152

(note that right now you have Daylight saving time: +1 hour)

And then check if the configuration of the computer that generated the calendar is correct, this means if is taking in account the Daylight saving time.